# .NET StructureMap IOC Ask for Instance and pass arguments

Tags: .net, arguments, structuremap

I am trying to ask to StructureMap for an instance and immediately pass parameters, to get the instance configurated (with parameters that I passed) but I don't know how to do this!

Here is the code , is simple to understand what I want to do.

```
class MyRegistry : Registry {

public MyRegistry() {

    // Use a new Connection for each instance
    For<ISQLRepositoryCommands>().Use(x => new SQLRepositoryCommands(DatabaseConnections.NewSqlConnection()));

    // WHAT I Want to do is.. remove the line above of code and let only this.
    For<ISQLRepositoryCommands>()
    .Use(x => {
        if( x.arguments != null ) {
            // Specific connection passed by parameter
            return new SQLRepositoryCommands( (SqlConnection) x.arguments[0]);
        }       
        // default connection
        return new SQLRepositoryCommands(DatabaseConnections.NewSqlConnection());
    }); 
}
```

}

The main

```
public static class StartUseStructureMap {
public static void Main() {
    // SQLRepositoryCommands with default connection associated
    var def = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ISQLRepositoryCommands>();

    // SQLRepositoryCommands with custom connection associated
    var personalizedConnection = new SqlConnection("cstring");
    var personalized = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ISQLRepositoryCommands>(new Arguments[] { new Argument(personalizedConnection) };
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This pseudo code is just my take and maybe there are better means of achieving it. But here is what I would do.

One thing you could use is the factory pattern but for that you would to tweak slightly your code.
But before we go to that step we have to get rid of the direct use of `SqlConnection` from you registration code. Although StructureMap doesn't require to register all the object explicitly we can do a wrapper that we could register in StructureMap and that will be invoked each time a SqlConnection should be created. That way we can put there a logic of SqlConnection created that depends on the connection string (empty or not). Here is how it could look like :

```
public interface ISQLConnectionWrapper
{
      SqlConnection GetConnection(string connectionName);
}

public class SQLConnectionWrapper : ISQLConnectionWrapper
{
    public SqlConnection GetConnection(string connectionName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionName))
            return DatabaseConnections.NewSqlConnection();
        return new SqlConnection(connectionName);
    }
}
```

Then we could tweak a little SQLRepositoryCommands class in order to take a builder in constructor that will return a wrapper which knows which connection to create :

```
public class SQLRepositoryCommands : ISQLRepositoryCommands
{
    private readonly Func<string, ISQLConnectionWrapper> _aBuilder;
    public SQLRepositoryCommands(Func<string, ISQLConnectionWrapper> aBuilder)
    {
        // guard clause first of course.
        _aBuilder = aBuilder;
    }

    public void DoWork(string connectionName = null)
    {
        var connection = _aBuilder(connectionName);
    }
}
```

I've added the DoWork method that actualy uses the builder to get the correct connection and to do the work.

Then here is how you could register it :

```
// register
ObjectFactory.Initialize( c =>
    {
              c.For<ISQLConnectionWrapper>().Use<SQLConnectionWrapper>();
              c.For<Func<string, SqlConnection>>().Use(d => (s => ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ISQLConnectionWrapper>().GetConnection(s)));
        c.For<ISQLRepositoryCommands>().Use<SQLRepositoryCommands>();
    });
```

And here is how you could use it :

```
// use
var command = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ISQLRepositoryCommands>();
command.DoWork("MyConnection"); // specific connection
command.DoWork(); // default connection
```

As I said. Maybe there is a better way to do it but this code should work.